# manipulación de bases de datos para regresión multivariada en OLS

Tags: python, base-de-datos

quiero nombrar las variables X y Y colocando una función de una regresión multivariada de determinación OLS con manejo de datos.iLoc, me aparece error en la linea y no se deja manipular

```
x = datos.iloc[:,[5]]
y = datos.prevalencia diabetes

x2 = sm.add_constant(x)
est = sm.OLS(y,x2)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())
```

Comment: Podrías proporcionar unos datos de prueba de tu dataframe? Además agrega el error que obtienes y detalla cual sería la salida esperada.